# ui-view do not bind to controler

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I using ui-router for the first time. I've check some tutorial, but nerver been able to make my project work.

I have a page with a controler, my file home.htm get request is complete but the ui-view do not display it.

index.htm

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script ng-include="'http://192.168.0.110/home.htm'"></script>
```

```
        angular
  .module('app', [
  'ui.router'
])



.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
      url:"/",
      templateUrl: 'http://192.168.0.110/home.htm',
      controller:'temperatureCTRL'
      })

}])

  .controller('temperatureCTRL', ["$scope", "$interval", "ArduinoService", function($scope, $interval, service) {
  var autoRefresh;
  $scope.channels = [];

  function startRefresh(){
    autoRefresh = $interval(function() {
    updateAjax();
    }, 5000);
  }


  function updateAjax() {
    service.getChannels(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return alert(err);
      }
      // puis les mets dans le scope
      $scope.channels = result.channels;
    })
  };

  $scope.init = function() { //on load page first get data
    updateAjax();
    startRefresh()
  }


  $scope.switchChannel = function($scope, channel) { // change name function
    var switchCh = {canal : $scope.canal, status : $scope.status}
    service.switchChannel(switchCh, function() {
    });
    updateAjax();
  };

  $scope.channelsClk = function($scope, channel) {
      var chanObj = {setPoint : $scope.setPoint, name : $scope.name, canal : $scope.canal
      };
      service.putChannels(chanObj, function() {
    });
  }

   $scope.stopRefresh = function() { //ng-mousedown
      $interval.cancel(autoRefresh);
    };

    $scope.restartRefresh = function() {
      startRefresh();
      console.log('lost focus');
    };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
      $scope.restartRefresh();
    });
}])


.service('ArduinoService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getChannels: function(cb) {
      $http.get('http://192.168.0.110/ajax_inputs')
        .success(function(result) {
          cb(null, result);
        });
    },
    switchChannel: function(switchCh, cb) {
      $http.put('http://192.168.0.110/switch', {
          switchCh
        })
        .success(function(result) {
          cb(null, true);
        });
    },

    putChannels: function(channels, cb) {
      $http.put('http://192.168.0.110/channels', {
          channels
        })
        .success(function(result) {
          cb(null, true);
        });
    }
  };
}])
```

now home.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- directive de repeat sur les données de vue channels -->
  <div class="IO_box" ng-repeat="channel in channels">
    <h2>{{channel.canal}}</h2>
    <button type="button" ng-click="switchChannel(channel, channel.canal)" ng-model="channel.status"> {{channel.status}} </button>
    <h2>
      <form> name:<br>
         <input type="text" name="Name" size="6" autocomplete="off" ng-model="channel.name" ng-focus="stopRefresh()" ng-blur="restartRefresh()">
         <button ng-click="channelsClk(channel, channel.name)">change</button>
  </form>
</h2>
    <br>
    <h4><span class="Ainput" >{{channel.temperature}}&#186;C</span></h4>
    <h2>Setpoint 
      <input type="number" name="setpoint" ng-model="channel.setPoint" ng-focus="stopRefresh()" ng-blur="restartRefresh()"
       min="5" max="30" step="0.5" size="1"> &#186;C   <br />
        <button ng-click="channelsClk(channel, channel.setPoint)">ok</button>
</h2>
    <h5>state: 
      <span class="permRun">{{channel.permRun}}</span>
</h5>
        <h5>
          <span class="AoutputChannel">{{channel.percent_out}}%</span>
</h5>
```

Comment: your ng-include line is wrong. home.htm is going to be loaded into the div with the directive ui-view on it

Comment: Yes man Fixed !!! simple detail but big trouble !! :P this is the correction: `   <div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="temperatureCTRL" ng-init="init()" ;>
    <div ng-include="'http://192.168.0.110/home.htm'"></div>
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to put the domain in the templateUrl. You're also trying to fetch it from your internal ip address but I think really you want to hit localhost which can just be written as `http://localhost:PORT` where PORT is whatever port your server is running on.

So your state definition should be:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('/', {
        url:"/",
        templateUrl: './home.htm', //assumes this template is in the same dir as the state definition file
        controller:'temperatureCTRL'
});
```

Also, if you want to display other templates you need to add `<div ui-view></div>` to your `home.htm` file so that ui-router knows where to display any nested templates (as Simon H commented there is no need for the ng-include).

Not related to ui-router but you shouldn't need to hardcode the domain name into your `$http` requests. Angular will use the current domain if you just write e.g. `'/ajax_inputs'` (which should be fine in your case because you are attempting to hit localhost). If you want to hit another domain then put that in a variable that can be easily changed.

```
getChannels: function(cb) {
    $http.get('/ajax_inputs')
        .then(function(result) { // .then with callback for error handling (success and error methods are being deprecated)
            cb(null, result);
    }, function(error) {
        // handle error here
    });
}
```

Comment: I use the domain only while programing because service and file are hosted on an arduino. BTW i'd realy like to learn how exactly put on var an adresse for this reason... :p . also, I tryed to add `<div ui-view></div>` to the home.htm but it have not solve my problem.

Comment: read to comment for solution, simon H solution work ! thank a lot guys